# Implicits over function closures in Scala

Tags: scala, implicit

I've been trying to understand implicits for Scala and trying to use them at work - one particular place im stuck at is trying to pass implicits in the following manner

```
object DBUtils {
  case class DB(val jdbcConnection: Connection) {

    def execute[A](op: =>Unit): Any = {
        implicit val con = jdbcConnection
        op
    }
}

object DB {
    def SQL(query: String)(implicit jdbcConnection: Connection): PreparedStatement = {
      jdbcConnection.prepareStatement(query)
    }
}

val someDB1 = DB(jdbcConnection)
val someDB2 = DB(jdbcConnection2)
val someSQL = SQL("SOME SQL HERE")
someDB1.execute{someSQL} 
someDB2.execute{someSQL}
```

Currently i get an execption saying that the SQL() function cannot find the implicit jdbcConnection.What gives and what do i do to make it work in the format i need?

Ps-:Im on a slightly older version of Scala(2.10.4) and cannot upgrade

Edit: Changed the problem statement to be more clear - I cannot use a single implicit connection in scope since i can have multiple DBs with different Connections

Comment: Have you read [this](http://blog.originate.com/blog/2013/10/21/reader-monad-for-dependency-injection/)? It describes different approaches to Dependency Injection using Scala code (including implicits).

Answer (score 1):

At the point where `SQL` is invoked there is no implicit value of type `Connection` in scope.

In your code snippet the declaration of `jdbcConnection` is missing, but if you change it from

```
val jdbcConnection = //...
```

to

```
implicit val jdbcConnection = // ...
```

then you will have an implicit instance of `Connection` in scope and the compiler should be happy.

Comment: You mean i should have it as case class DB(impicit val jdbcConnection: Connection)? - tried and it does not work,also i want it to use the connection from within the case class since there can be multiple DB in the same scope and hence a single implicit connection wont cut it for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
implicit val con = jdbcConnection // define implicit here
val someDB = DB(jdbcConnection)
val someSQL = SQL("SOME SQL HERE") // need implicit here
someDB.execute{someSQL}
```

The implicit must be defined in the scope where you need it. (In reality, it's more complicated, because there are rules for looking elsewhere, as you can find in the documentation. But the simplest thing is to make sure the implicit is available in the scope where you need it.)

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes

1) `execute` method take a function from `Connection` to `Unit`

2) Instead of this `val someDB1 = DB(jdbcConnection)` use this `someDB1.execute{implicit con => someSQL}`

```
object DBUtils {
  case class DB(val jdbcConnection: Connection) {

    def execute[A](op: Connection =>Unit): Any = {
        val con = jdbcConnection
        op(con)
    }
}
```

Here is the complete code.

```
object DB {
    def SQL(query: String)(implicit jdbcConnection: Connection): PreparedStatement = {
      jdbcConnection.prepareStatement(query)
    }
}

val someDB1 = DB(jdbcConnection)
val someDB2 = DB(jdbcConnection2)
val someSQL = SQL("SOME SQL HERE")
someDB1.execute{implicit con => someSQL} 
someDB2.execute{implicit con => someSQL}
```

Comment: This is what ive resorted to in my code currently - but i hate the sight of having an implicit con every time - i do not wish to write it every time i make a SQL call.Problem is i have a lot of overlapping calls between DBs and i have written more implicit wrappers to return case class objects from each SQL i execute - hence i end up writing "implicit con =>" some times more than 10 times in the same file if i have 10 queries - an effect i do not desire